# How can I cancel my Ubuntu installation in progress?

Tags: 12.10, system-installation, windows-7, kubuntu

I have a dual boot setup with Windows 7 and Ubuntu, but I was having problems with Ubuntu 12.10.

I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, but the installation has taken  20 hours already and is not advancing. It's stuck on `Unpacking flashplugin-installer`. How can I cancel the installation and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** you can cancel a currant install by holding down the power button for 10 seconds. Then just start over the install from scratch. good luck, it happens to all of us at some point.

Comment: In general, holding down the power button is a bad idea. While file system corruption may not be relevant if you're reinstalling from scratch, I'd still prefer to try [Alt+PrntSc R-E-I-S-U-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) as the preferred option to restart. You could also go to a console Ctrl+Alt+F1 and view the logs and try to determine what the problem is. (Especially if this happens again)